# How to redirect from Login to View already redirected from?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

if user is not logged in and i redirected him to **Login** View how can i redirect him to the previous view he was trying to open before **Login**??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `ReturnUrl` query string parameter that will be present in the Request. The way that the Forms Authentication module works is that if it intercepts a request for which the user is not authorized for example `/Home/Index` he will be redirected to the login page and added a query string parameter called ReturnUrl pointing to the initially requested resource: `/Account/Logon?ReturnUrl=%2FHome%2FIndex`.

So now inside your `Logon` action (GET or POST) you could retrieve the `ReturnUrl` query string parameter and redirect the user there.

This pattern is illustrated in action when you create a brand new ASP.NET MVC application with the Internet Template in Visual Studio. Just look at the AccountController and the LogOn action which uses it.

Comment: you mean this code `if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
            {

                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, false);
                if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
                {
                    return Redirect(returnUrl);
                }
                else
                {

                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                   
                }`

Answer (score 0):

Usually I Userd Javascript history object for This

```
<script>
function goBack()
{
window.history.back()
}
</script>
```

Comment: where do you use it ?? in the login view ??